# How do you read the previous character in a text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

Suppose a I have a file open on C++ and I read in some characters already. Is there a way that I can see what the previous character is from where I currently am in the file?

Comment: By storing the previous read in a variable? *"I read in some characters already"*

Comment: Do you have access to the characters that you read?

Comment: @WeatherVane that is too easy.  This task obviously requires many library calls.

Comment: @MartinJames .. as suggested by answers below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in iostream class called seekg(and seekp). It is like a file pointer. If you want to read the character before the current one, just move the pointer a byte ahead(since char only uses a byte). The format will be: IOobjectName.seekg(-1, ios::cur); If u want more information, check out this website! http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/ Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use istream::seekg(), like:

```
int prevChar = 0;
is.seekg(-2, is.cur); // -2 because we want to read the previous char, -1 will move the position to the current char again 
if (is.good()) {
  prevChar = is.get();
}
```

This will move the current read position to the previous character.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your -2. When I do `is.open("[...]", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::ate);`, `is.seekg(-1, is.cur);` does seem to find the last character of my file. -2 does not.

Answer (score -1):

You could store the last line that you read, and get the length, and then get that last character by trimming the string to the length...

Answer (score -1):

If you know the which in row the character is (perhaps getting length of the file, and count already read characters), you can use seekg. For example:

```
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(file);
myFile.seekg(5); //fifth character from start
```